# In C++, can I declare a template struct with a template parameter unused in the definition?

Tags: c++, templates, struct

Recently I'm reading the source code from [spirit-v2-json](https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json), and I have been confused with the [following code](https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/blob/master/json.hpp#L9):

```
template <typename Tag> struct Literal 
{ 
    bool operator==(Literal const&) const { return true;  } 
    bool operator< (Literal const&) const { return false; } 
};

typedef Literal<struct tag_undefined> Undefined;
typedef Literal<struct tag_null>  Null;
```

Question 1: What's the meaning of the `tag` parameter in the template of `Literal`? It is unused.
Question 2: The `struct tag_undefined` and `struct tag_null` haven't been defined even declared, why can we use them as template parameters?

Comment: In your example, for any (different) type `A` and `B` the structures `Literal<A>` and `Literal<B>` are completely different types. That is probably the purpose here, to be able to create separate distinct types using a single simple structure template.

Comment: For Q2, they are declared in situ, right there by `struct tag_undefined`.

Comment: You're forward declaring `tag_undefined` and `tag_null` in the template argument list. If you remove the `struct` keyword you'll get the compile error you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for comments above. `struct tag_undefined` and `tag_null` are declared in the template argument list but not defined, does that mean I can use a structure undefined as a template parameter?

Comment: It's OK as long as you don't instantiate it. Instantiating a template with an incomplete type is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @101010 No, this is not UB. The standard actually says that "A template type argument may be an incomplete type." ([\[temp.arg.type\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.type))

Comment: @cpplearner I didn't say that a template type can't be an incomplete type. I said that trying to instantiate such a template is UB.

Comment: @101010 But in the source code of this project it does instantiate this template with an incomplete type...

Comment: Instantiating an incomplete type is not UB, it is a compilation error. @huron - in the code you share this doesn't happen

Comment: If the types `Undefined` and `Null` get instantiated this is not the same as instantiating their tag types

Comment: @101010 Instantiating a *standard library* template with an incomplete type is UB *unless otherwise specified*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the `tag` parameter is to differentiate between different types. There is no requirement for them to display any difference in functionality, but they need to be distinct classes. As this differentiation is the only purpose of the `tag` parameter and as it isn't used in any way in the template class itself, it is OK to use incomplete in-situ types directly in the `typedef`.

Why would you want to do this? In the above use case the code uses this template to define two distinct types, `Undefined` and `Null`. They could have just as easily created those types directly, using `struct Null` and `struct Undefined`, but then they would have had to define the operators `operator=` and `operator<` separately, which was probably considered a waste. Using a type tag in this way achieves the same effect with template code re-use.

If you look later on in the code the two types are actually passed as parameters to `boost::variant`, which is a "multi-type, single value" methodology to represent values in a variable type. Here the code wants to have the concept of `Undefined` and `Null` as distinct types in this multi-type system (I guess to represent undefined or null json objects).

**UPDATE:**
As per OP request, here is some code to demonstrate where incomplete types can and can not be used:

```
struct incomplete_struct;
struct complete_struct{};

template<typename tag>
struct some_templ
{};

template<typename tag>
struct some_other_templ
{
    tag member;
};

int main()
{
    some_templ<incomplete_struct> a;          //OK - incomplete template param type but not used in class so not instantiated
    some_templ<struct inline_incomplete> b;   //OK - as above

    some_other_templ<complete_struct> c;      //OK  - complete_struct is complete type
    some_other_templ<incomplete_struct> d;    //Compile error - incomplete type, and used in template - thus instantiation of incomplete_struct is required but impossible

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the comments of this question, @101010 said that instantiating a template with an incomplete type is undefined behaviour, is he right?

Comment: Instantiating a template with incomplete type is not Undefined Behaviour - it is a compilation error. Note that in the code you're asking about, no such instantiation takes place

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand... Can you show me a simple example where such instantiation takes place?

Comment: If I write code like this`Undefined tmp{};`, does such instantiation happened?

Comment: I edited answer above to address your comment question. `Undefined tmp` (with or without the `{}`) is OK for the same reason that `a` and `b` above are OK. It is the template type, not its tag, which is being instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the template parameter is left unused, and is used only to differentiate between the type.

Yes,  you can use undefined types as template parameters as long they're not used. Templates are a bit like a find&replace supported by the compiler, and since the template parameter is not used,  it is not pasted anywhere in the code.